# Wordpress.Com blog XML/Site map download

Tags: wordpress

Hi I happened to know that we can access the sitemap for a WordPress (WordPress.com) blog using a URL. I am quite not sure about that now, though I downloaded the XML once, I forgot the URl.

Please tell me how can I download it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually a sitemap is just located at the web root of the site. If you place it anywhere else, there will be URIs that it won't be able to point to. So naturally, for Wordpress.com blogs, it'll be at `{domain.tld}/sitemap.xml` —e.g.

- http://daytonward.wordpress.com/sitemap.xml
- http://sviehb.wordpress.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: Thank you Very Much, Lese, Got it for my [wordpress blog](http://theaterbalcony.wordpress.com)!!